# How to get a single record from One to Many polymorphic relation in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two model with `One to Many` polymorphic relation like:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Address', 'addressable');
    }
}
```

In address model there is a column named `is_primary` and one user can have only one primary address. Now in user update form I want to get the primary address only from the address model.

I know I can pull all addresses and check which one is the primary address or this:

```
public function primaryAddress()
{
    return $this->addresses()->where('is_primary',true)->first();
}
```

But the problem is the form field doesn't get the value and I want to access the primary address like `$user->address_line_1`

How can i achive this goal?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/relationship-macros?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=LN%20141%20-%20Laravel%20Eloquent%20Relationships%20Through%20Macros&utm_content=LN%20141%20-%20Laravel%20Eloquent%20Relationships%20Through%20Macros+CID_ac36a12801d2533197d91bc100eed131&utm_source=email%20marketing&utm_term=Read%20MOre

Answer (score 0):

You cas use an accessor for that:

```
    public function getPrimaryAddressAttribute()
{
    return $this->addresses()->where('is_primary',true)->first();
}
```

and now you get $user->primary_address

if you want to direcly access the lines do something like:

```
    public function getAddressLine1Attribute()
{
    return $this->addresses()->where('is_primary',true)->first()->address_line_1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the address is not a single field, there are line_1,line_2,state,zip,country and some other fields.